# NavigationService won't navigate after going there via absolute Navigation

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigationservice, prism-7

I am currently working on a `Xamarin.Forms` application that is targeting `UWP`, `iOS` and `android`.

After implementing a login dialog I am navigating a logged in user to a `SomeContentPage`, which I now want to be enclosed into a `NavigationPage` (and perhaps later on inside a `MasterDetailPage`).

I am trying to reset the navigation stack by using a `/`-prefix for a absolute navigation route, which will bring the user to the desired page and clear the stack:

```cs
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationPage/SomeContentPage");
```

Following, from this page there is no more relative navigation possible:

```cs
var navigationResult = await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("AnotherContentPage")
```

It seems like that there is everything going well "inside" the navigation system (`navigationResult.Success` is `true`) but the app is not navigating to the `AnotherContentPage` at all.

If I navigate without the `/`-Prefix, the upcoming navigation calls work as expected:

```cs
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/SomeContentPage");
```

I am really concerned and I already investigated very hard on this.

I don't know if I am just not understanding something properly in the Prism.Forms NavigationService concept or if I am trying something impossible here.

I re-read the `Prism.Forms` documentation, watched several YouTube-tutorials and read many blog posts about navigation in `Prism.Forms`.

I am near to desparation right now.

I really feel bad asking this and I am really questioning my internet-research-skills at this moment, but it would be great, if someone of you could give me some advice, how to handle this.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!